# FDA API not working since last month

Tags: openfda

The FDA API is not able to extract data for the month of May and June. The API used in collecting the data for May is given below: 'https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20230501+TO+20230515]+AND+device.manufacturer_d_name:"INTUITIVE SURGICAL, INC"&limit=1000'

But the API response is:
<Response [404]>
{
"error": {
"code": "NOT_FOUND",
"message": "No matches found!"
}
}

What would be the reason for the response and by when would the API be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

All Adverse Events endpoints are updated quarterly at roughly the beginning of the following quarter. That update has been completed for Q2, so those two months should now be available.

Regards,

Violet Wren

openFDA Tech Lead